# TS error, "Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'string'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

This is more of a general question about using TS with Express. Am I expected to extend the `Query` interface for every single route on my backend? For instance, if I want to pull out some params,

```
router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const { id } = req.query
  // do something
})
```

I would get thrown the error that is in the title. I've tried doing something like,

```
const { id }: { id: string } = req.query
```

or

```
const id = req.query!.id
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What are my options in such a situation?

Comment: `const { id } = req.query` this seems working fine for me. at first, I was also getting the same error but after some time I can see id with type `string | Query | (string | Query)[]`

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work -- are you importing `Query` from express?